# SQL SERVER exec Stored Procedure to CASE WHEN condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a query that select some table from another server (with IP LINK), it's okay with table select. But when I put a FUNCTION (Store procedure) into CASE WHEN condition,  it doesnt work..

```
SELECT
    CASE
WHEN A.TGL IS NULL THEN
    B.TGL
ELSE
    [123.123.111].[DBNAME].dbo.Func_S(A.NOREK, B.NAMA, A.TGL)
END AS TGL_ANSURAN
FROM
    [123.123.111].[DBNAME].dbo.TblName AS A
JOIN [123.123.111].[DBNAME].dbo.TblName2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

when I execute that, error message shows :

> *"[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Remote function reference '[123.123.111].[DBNAME].dbo.Func_S' is not allowed, and the column
>   name '123.123.111' could not be found or is ambiguous."*

What's wrong with my query? the `Func_S` is exist and my server has already linked with network server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use openquery to select functions - So try if this should work.

```
select
   a.*
from
   OPENQUERY ( [123.123.111],
'
SELECT
    CASE
WHEN A.TGL IS NULL THEN
    B.TGL
ELSE
   [DBNAME].dbo.Func_S(A.NOREK, B.NAMA, A.TGL)
END AS TGL_ANSURAN
FROM
   [DBNAME].dbo.TblName AS A
JOIN [DBNAME].dbo.TblName2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
' ) a
```